# How can I modify a value of a dictionary that inside another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a variable "Persons" that contain the following dictionary,

```
persons = {
    'mohammed': {'age': 25, 'job': 'programmer', 'city': 'tripoli'}
}
```

what I want to do is to modify any valus of the 'mohammed' items which is the key of the persons dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
persons["mohammad"]["job"] = "teacher"
```